# Calculating sum of certain previously inputted numbers

Tags: c

This program should calculate the sum of all numbers whose digits are in descending order. It stops you from inputting if the number isn't a whole number. I think that the problem might be because of the sum variable, but I don't know how to fix it.
Edit: Per @user3386109 request, here is the output I get:
4321
75
56
4,79
0

The sum should be 4396, as sum of 4321 and 75. Not 0.
Sorry for the unclear question I am quite new to this.

```
int n, last, secondlast, sum, c = 0;
int temp;

while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
    sum = 0;
    while (temp > 0) {
        last = temp % 10;
        secondlast = (temp / 10) % 10;
        if (secondlast > last) {
            c++;
            sum = sum + temp;
        }
        temp = temp / 10;

    }
}

if (c == 0) {
    printf("There are no numbers that meet the requirements\n");
}
else {
    printf("%d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: You never assign to `temp` before using its value in the `while`.

Comment: What the text says, and what the code does, are two totally different things. An example might help clear things up.

Comment: btw, the `while` loop should be `while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1)`. The current code will result in an infinite loop if `scanf` returns end-of-file (EOF).

Comment: Thanks for the example. But 78 doesn't have digits in descending order. And I'm confused by `4,79`. Are you in a locale where `,` is used as the decimal point?

Comment: I am so sorry, its meant to be 75. I will edit it now. As for 4,79, I get the same output (0) when it is written as 4.79, if you meant that. I am sorry for the missunderstanding.

Comment: @user3386109 asked because it wasn't clear. While coding you need to use the dot by the way. Writing 4,79 and 4.79 are two different things.

Comment: Thank you. How can I clear it up?

Comment: The way I would approach this is to write a function that determines whether a number has descending digits. The input to the function is the number. The output from the function is either true or false. The `main` code should set `sum` to zero. Then for each number, call the function. If it returns true, then add the number to the `sum`. I'm assuming that you've learned about functions. This exercise seems designed to encourage you to use a function.

Comment: OT: `while (scanf("%d", &n)) {` --> `while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {`

Comment: BTW: Is input like 444 valid or invalid?

Comment: Yes, I made an edit because 78 was a mistake. It was meant to be 75. My bad.

Comment: And no, that input is not valid.

Comment: About @user3386109s suggestion, I know the very basics of functions from C++, but sadly in our C lessons functions are later down the line. I assume it will be quite similar but I am still pretty lost on that.

Comment: Not fully tested but this should get you started: https://ideone.com/vwHtZF

Comment: Thank you, you are all lifesavers.

Answer (score 0):

As @Support Ukraine commented, this code gets the job done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int descendingDigits(int n)
{
    int current = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    while(n)
    {
        int this = n % 10;
        if (this <= current) return 0;
        current = this;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return 1;
}
 
int main(void) {
 
    int sum = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int n = 0;
 
    while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        if (descendingDigits(n))
        {
            sum = sum + n;
            c = 1;
        }
    }
 
    if (c == 0) {
        printf("There are no numbers that meet the requirements\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`%10` operations are really not the best way to determine if the digits are descending.  It works, but it seems like overkill to use `scanf` to convert the input to an integer at all, since it's much easier to know if the digits are in order if you leave them as a string.  It's tempting to check if the digits of the string are descending and only convert to an integer value if they are, but it seems like a bad idea to parse the string twice.  In other words; read the input as a string and do not convert, then compute the integer value while you are looking at the digits to see if they are descending.  This is aesthetically appealing, since you minimize computations.  (eg, if the input string is "47901", you shouldn't waste cpu cycles converting that to the integer 47901; after you see that 7 is not less than 4, you can abort).

eg:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* If the string s represents an integer
 * with (strictly) descending digits, return
 * its integer representation (base 10).  Else
 * return 0.
 */
unsigned
is_descending(const char *s)
{
    unsigned rv = 0;
    int last = '9' + 1;
    while( *s ){
        if( isdigit(*s) && *s < last ){
            rv = 10 * rv + *s - '0';
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
        last = *s++;
    }
    return rv;
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[64];
    unsigned sum = 0;
    while( scanf("%63s", buf) == 1 ){
        sum += is_descending(buf);
    }
    printf("sum: %u\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this does not handle negative numbers well, but it's not clear how you want to deal with that.  Left as an exercise for the reader.